# Will Installing KDE Desktop block me from getting UBUNTU security updates and newer versions of UBUNTU?

Tags: updates, kde

I want to install KDE desktop.If i install KDE then will i get  UBUNTU security updates and newer versions of UBUNTU?
OR, Will be blocked from getting  getting them?

Comment: If you install the K DEsktop from Ubuntu sources; it'll only mean you just have another choice at login of what DE you want to use for that session. All updates will continue, including upgrades (though they'll be larger, as you'll have updates for your original DE & new DE too).

Comment: That Solved my problem! ..................Thanks to guiverc and muru